# Fetch Record through the parent_id instead of entity_id in Magento2

Tags: magento2

Here I want a Billing and Shopping addresses according to order_id. I receive a order data in my order object but it will give me just one record according to entity id.I want both address of order(billing and shipping).How to get the record through parent id instead of entity id.

```
 protected $order;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address $order
) {
$this->order = $order;
}

public function orderlist($orderid) {
$order = $this->order->load($orderid);        
$billingAddress = $this->order->getData();

echo "<pre>";
print_r($billingAddress);
die;

}
```

Comment: what parentId do you mean?

Comment: database field.

Comment: parentid of order, address, .... ? I don't know what parentid you mean to which entity.

order and address don't have parentids, that's why I'm asking

Comment: just use getParentId() instead of entity_id